# How do I pass the parameter from js to fortran program?

Tags: javascript, r, node.js, fortran

I'm trying to pass parameter values from js program to Fortran program.

Here's the [link to fortran program](https://github.com/holstius/CALINE4/blob/master/src/libcaline4.f) 

Here's the parameter values I want to pass into CALINE4 SUBROUTINE in fotran program from js code:

```
    1, 30, 0, 1.8,
    1, 0, -5000, 0, 5000, 30, 0, 0, 7500, 30,
    1, 270, 6, 1000, 15, 10, 10, 
    1, 28, 0, 0
```

So my difficulty is passing the parameter values from my javascript code to fortran program and printing the returned predicted variable in js.

There is [fortran package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fortran) available on npm which I have used to run the fortran code. I'm able to only run the fortran code using the fortran package but unable to pass the parameter values and get the returned value by the fortran program.

Here's the program in js what I been done so far:

```
 // imports fortran package
    const fotran = require("fortran");
 // imports libcaline4.f, that I'm trying to pass parameter values
    const caline = require("libcaline4.f");

 // I'm trying to pass the values to the function
 // in libcaline4.f code and collect the returned value
 // in val variable. 
 // This doesn't work as libcaline4.f is not js file
  var val = caline(
    1, 30, 0, 1.8,
    1, 0, -5000, 0, 5000, 30, 0, 0, 7500, 30,
    1, 270, 6, 1000, 15, 10, 10, 
    1, 28, 0, 0
);

// Executing fotran program using fortran npm package.
// The libcaline4.f executed but without sending any parameter values 
var fort_prog_exe = fotran(caline,(err, data) => {
console.log(data);
});)
```

Here's the similar thing done with R instead of js. As I'm unfamiliar with R I'm unable to make use of it.`https://github.com/holstius/CALINE4/blob/master/R/CALINE4.R`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here's the repo : https://github.com/holstius/CALINE4

Comment: So `fotran` (sic!), or `fort` or what? Are you showing your exact code?

Comment: So is it your exact real code or not now? What kind of difficulty do you have?

Comment: My difficulty is to pass the parameter from my javascript program to fortran program.
I have figured out the way of running fortran program using fortran module found from npm website. 
But the thing is how would I pass this values to  this :
CALINE4.Fortran <- function(

Comment: So what happens when you try the code in the question? What kind of difficulty? Error messages? Which ones? Wrong results? Which results? We don't have a crystal ball in which we could seebyour screen. We cannot read your mind. **Give us more details.**

Comment: There's not error yet until I know how to pass parameter values to the function in fortran. 
I just figured out how to run fortran program in js.


It's bit difficult for me, never tried of this type. BTW I don't want to write that fortran program from scratch.

Comment: So how do you run it?

Comment: I run in node.js environment.

Comment: But which code do you use? What happens when you run it? Really we need as many details as possible to see what you have. Maybe you think it is obvious, because it is in the question above, but no, it is not obvious. It is not very clear which part of the question is what.

Comment: @VladimirF thanks for trying to help me. I have reformatted the question properly.

Comment: But we need your javascript code. Even if it is incomplete or not working properly.

Comment: @VladimirF I have reformatted the question and details again.

Thank you.

Comment: So it seems your problem is something else. Your problem is not *"How do I pass parameters?"* your problem is *"How can I run a Fortran function from js at all?"*. Specify your problem as exactly as possible, otherwise people will be confused.

Comment: What happened after you did `const caline = require("libcaline4.f");`? Was there any error message?

Comment: What happened after you did `var val = caline(...
);`??? Was there any error message? Which error message? We need **details**.

Comment: @VladimirF My problem is not with how to run fortran code as I have used the fortran package from npm to run fortran code.
Then problem is I can run fortran code but how do I pass any arguments or parameters to that fortran code from js.

Thank you.

Comment: And what happens when you run it?